# Netflix Conductor Python client generates an error when creating a task

Tags: python, python-3.x, netflix, conductor

I tried to use the Python client code from Netflix Conductor to crate a task but I get errors no matter how I call it:

```
from conductor import conductor
import json

server_url = "http://localhost:8080/api"

task_def = '''[{
      "name": "verify_if_idents_are_added",
      "retryCount": 3,
      "retryLogic": "FIXED",
      "retryDelaySeconds": 10,
      "timeoutSeconds": 300,
      "timeoutPolicy": "TIME_OUT_WF",
      "responseTimeoutSeconds": 180,
      "ownerEmail": "a@a.com"
    }]'''

metadataClient = conductor.MetadataClient(server_url)
metadataClient.registerTaskDef(task_def)
```

```
ERROR: {"status":400,"message":"Validation failed, check below errors for detail.","retryable":false,"validationErrors":[{"path":"updateTaskDef.arg0.ownerEmail","message":"ownerEmail cannot be empty"}]}
...

HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://localhost:8080/api/metadata/taskdefs
```

Also:

```
task_def_json = json.loads(task_def)
metadataClient.registerTaskDef(task_def_json)
```

Gets:

```
ERROR: {"code":"INTERNAL_ERROR","message":"INTERNAL_ERROR - Cannot deserialize instance of `com.netflix.conductor.common.metadata.tasks.TaskDef` out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 1, column: 1]","retryable":false,"instance":"d4f36b3da428"}
...
HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http://localhost:8080/api/metadata/taskdefs
```

How can I create a task with this Python module?

Answer (score 3):

Because it's so simple of a HTTP requests I would recommend using requests to post directly rather than that outdated python client that probably nobody uses.
Here's a DIY task definition post:

```
import requests

req_header={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

task_def_endpoint='http://localhost:8080/api/metadata/taskdefs'
task_def = '''[{"name": "verify_if_idents_are_added", "retryCount": 3, "retryLogic": "FIXED", "retryDelaySeconds": 10, "timeoutSeconds": 300, "timeoutPolicy": "TIME_OUT_WF", "responseTimeoutSeconds": 180, "ownerEmail": "a@a.com"}]'''

response= requests.post(task_def_endpoint, data=task_def, headers=req_header)
print(response.status_code)
```

**Now you can skip the extra info below and be done with it, but carry on reading if you are curious.**

If you curious what is going on with the conductor package that came with Netflix python client, look at https://github.com/Netflix/conductor/blob/master/client/python/conductor/conductor.py

You'll see that both MetadataClient's registerTaskDef() and updateTaskDef() are actually calling the update or PUT endpoint, not the create (POST endpoint). Assuming you have `verify_if_idents_are_added` **already defined on conductor**, eg via

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '[{"name": "verify_if_idents_are_added", "retryCount": 3, "retryLogic": "FIXED", "retryDelaySeconds": 10, "timeoutSeconds": 300, "timeoutPolicy": "TIME_OUT_WF", "responseTimeoutSeconds": 180, "ownerEmail": "a%40a.com"}]' 'http://localhost:8080/api/metadata/taskdefs'
```

you'll find the following code works (notice that the task is not in a List element anymore cause that's what is what expected by the PUT endpoint):

```
task_def = '''{"name": "verify_if_idents_are_added", "retryCount": 3, "retryLogic": "FIXED", "retryDelaySeconds": 10, "timeoutSeconds": 300, "timeoutPolicy": "TIME_OUT_WF", "responseTimeoutSeconds": 180, "ownerEmail": "a@a.com"}'''

metadataClient.registerTaskDef(task_def)
```

So the registerTaskDef of this client is totally smurfed in my opinion. You can create PR to fix it or just use `requests` to do what you need.

Comment: Thank you! Excellent answer! You showed a workaround and explained the cause of the bug. I created a PR just to see what happens. Strange how no one reported this bug for 3 years.